# How to git stash show changes to only one files?

Tags: git, diff

I know you can use `git stash show stashID -p` see changes to files which would be applied if the contents of specific stash are popped. Is there a way to see only the diff to one particular file? The help section for `git stash` says

`By default, the command shows the diffstat, but it will accept any format known to git diff`

but `git stash show stashID -p <filepath>` doesn't work as `<filepath>` seems to be treated as another stash id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your file path after `--`

```
git show stash@{n} -- path/to/file
```

(Here `-p` is superfluous since it's the default behavior)

Comment: Be careful with `git show <stash>`: stash refs point to commits with 2 or 3 parents (because that's how stashes work) and `git show` therefore treats them as merge commits, which results in `git show` showing them as *combined diffs* by default. Combined diffs omit things! You will usually want `git diff <stash>^ <stash> -- <path>` here.